# Как передвинуть QLabel вправо и влево?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qt5, qlabel

Я хочу чтобы это двигало мой объект слева направо, начинаясь там, где расположен объект и заканчивая там же.

Мне нужно создавать каждый раз новую переменную? Я пробовал сделать это в цикле перечисляя `setStartValue`, `setEndValue` и `Start()`, но он выполнял самое последнее

```
def doAnim(self):
    self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.alertVer, b"geometry")
    self.anim.setDuration(200)
    self.anim.setStartValue(QRect(25, 90, 16, 16))
    self.anim.setEndValue(QRect(65, 90, 16, 16))
    self.anim.start()
```

вот что я пытался

```
    zet = 0
    while zet != 4:
        self.anim.setStartValue(QRect(75, 90, 16, 16))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QRect(65, 90, 16, 16))
        self.anim.start()
        self.anim.setStartValue(QRect(65, 90, 16, 16))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QRect(85, 90, 16, 16))
        self.anim.start()
        print("1")
        self.anim.setStartValue(QRect(85, 90, 16, 16))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QRect(75, 90, 16, 16))
        self.anim.start()
        zet += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class AnimationArea(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnimationArea, self).__init__()

        self.enemy = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World', self)
        self.enemy.move(5, 30)  
        self.enemyAnimation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.enemy, b'pos')

        # установить начальное значение для анимации; если мы не предоставим это, 
        # анимация будет использовать конечное значение, как только оно закончится.
        self.enemyAnimation.setStartValue(self.enemy.pos())

        self.enemyAnimation.setStartValue(QtCore.QPointF(5, 30))
        self.enemyAnimation.setKeyValueAt(0.3, QtCore.QPointF(80, 30))                   
        self.enemyAnimation.setKeyValueAt(0.5, QtCore.QPointF(200, 30))
        self.enemyAnimation.setKeyValueAt(0.7, QtCore.QPointF(250, 250))
        self.enemyAnimation.setKeyValueAt(0.8, QtCore.QPointF(290, 30))
        self.enemyAnimation.setEndValue(QtCore.QPointF(5, 30))
        self.enemyAnimation.setDuration(8000)

    def start(self):
        self.enemyAnimation.start()


class AniWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AniWindow, self).__init__()

        self.animationArea = AnimationArea()

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.animationArea.start)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.animationArea)
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    aniWindow = AniWindow()
    aniWindow.resize(640, 480)   
    aniWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]